# ¿Por que los numeros decimales en programacion se representan con un punto y no con una coma?

Tags: decimal

En todos los lenguajes de programación que eh usado siempre que se trabaja con números decimales estos se representan con un punto, lo cual es contrario a varias definiciones como:

> Los números decimales son aquellos que se representan con una coma y
> que tienen una parte entera(a la izquierda de la coma) y otra parte
> decimal (a la derecha de la coma).

*Concepto tomado de https://www3.gobiernodecanarias.org/medusa/ecoblog/crodalf/numeros-decimales-concepto/*

o

> Podemos decir que un número decimal es aquel que está formado por una
> parte entera y una parte decimal, separadas por una coma, y representa
> cantidades que no son enteras.

*Definición tomada de https://www.mundoprimaria.com/recursos-matematicas/numeros-decimales*

Por ejemplo en la consola de programación en javascript hacemos una simple división:

```javascript
179/4
--> 44.75
```

Nos retorna un decimal separado por un punto y no por una coma. ¿Por que ocurre esto?

Nota: *Si esta pregunta no va para este sitio por favor háganlo saber.*

Comment: La verdad es que no hay nada más que convención. Como explica ruben, se usa la convención anglosajona. Pero no hay nada que impida representar los literales con comas en vez de puntos, o con el símbolo que escojas; es cuestión de definirlo de esa forma en el lenguaje que diseñes.

Comment: @SJuan76 no sabia que se podía definir si en lo que te refieres es a decirle al lenguaje que te tome los decimales con punto ¿Como puedo definirlo por ejemplo en javascript?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a modificar ligeramente el lenguaje de programación o a ejecutar instrucciones como `replace`?

Comment: Los sistemas operativos más influyentes han sido creados en EUA y usan internamente el punto como [separador de decimal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separador_decimal). De ahí el término original *floating point*.

Comment: No es que lo puedas cambiar en un lenguaje. Pero si defines tu propio lenguaje puedes definirlo como quieras; no hay nada que haga que todos los lenguajes tengan que usar el punto.

Comment: Usando lenguaje c# prueba cambiando la configuración regional en la aplicación: System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-MX");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Antes que nada no se trata de un problema específico de los lenguajes de programación, ni siquiera lo llamaría un problema. Simplemente podríamos decir que se trata de una "inconsistencia cultural". Varios siglos antes que existieran las computadoras, tampoco el mundo había llegado a un consenso en como diferenciar las unidades de la parte decimal, hubo varias formas, pero con el tiempo prevalecieron dos: el punto, usado principalmente en Gran Bretaña y sus zonas de influencia, y la coma en Europa occidental, (más adelante América Latina) y Rusia entre otros. Cuando aparecen las primeras computadoras modernas, podemos decir que las más conocidas y exitosas lo hicieron principalmente en Estados Unidos, por lo cual los lenguajes y el hardware que marcaron el camino, adoptaron la notación que bien podríamos llamar "anglo sajona".

Aún cuando el desarrollo de nuevos lenguajes no está atado al mundo anglo sajón, es claro que la industria ha preferido mantener este estándar de facto.

Por otro lado, vale la pena mencionar, según consta en la página de [Fundéu - Fundación del español urgente](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/decimales-coma-y-punto-son-ambas-validas/):

> En la Ortografía de la lengua española, de las Academias de la Lengua,
> se señala que, «con el fin de promover un proceso tendente hacia la
> unificación, se recomienda el uso del punto como signo separador de
> los decimales», al tiempo que aclara que la coma sigue siendo
> igualmente válida, de modo que puede escribirse tanto 11.5 como 11,5
> para la cantidad de ‘once y medio’

Por ultimo no está de más señalar que aún cuando los lenguajes prefieren el uso del punto como separador decimal, siempre tendremos la posibilidad de modificar la representación del dato, regionalizarlo, o "formatearlo" de acuerdo a los usos y costumbres, aunque claro, esto implica necesariamente convertir ese número en una cadena con formato.

Para más información: [Separador decimal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separador_decimal)

Answer (score 3):

La explicación es bastante simple: en el sistema inglés las comas se cambian por puntos y los puntos por comas. Ej:

> 1.000 (mil) en inglés sería 1,000

Y 1,4 sería

> 1,4 -> 1.4

Fijate que en notación cientifica 1400 sería 1,4x10e2, a esto en inglés se le llama *floating point* y en español puedes llamarlo tanto *representación de coma flotante* como *punto flotante*.

En resumen, como actualmente el mundo se comunica en inglés, los ordenadores también.

Comment: No estoy seguro de que tu respuesta aclare totalmente la duda planteada por el OP, de hecho, por más que leo tu publicación no logro entender lo que tratas de decir. Saludos

Comment: Le estoy diciendo que en programación se utiliza el punto decimal por convención inglesa.

Comment: Cuando pones 1.000 no se si quieres decir mil o el numero entero **uno** escrito en decimal.

Comment: Editado para aclarar que es mil 

Comment: Por favor, proporciona detalles adicionales en tu respuesta. Tal como está escrita actualmente, es difícil entender tu solución.

Comment: "1400 sería 1,4x10e2" eso da 140 y no 1400 como dices.